# Show contact name that save in outlook app as Caller ID?

Tags: iphone

I use outlook app on iPhone for work email/calender/contacts. The app is great however iPhone does not recognize incoming number that is matching a saved contact inside outlook app. So the phone only show the phone number instead of contact name.

is there any setting I need to enable?

Thanks,
/S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the iPhone can use the contacts in Outlook app.
However you can syncrhonize your contacts through iTunes :

1. Connect your iPhone or iPod touch to your computer using the cable provided with your device or by placing the iPhone or iPod touch in the Apple Universal Dock
2. iTunes opens automatically when connected to your computer.
3. In iTunes, in the source list, under Devices, click the entry for your iPhone or iPod touch.
4. Click the Info tab.
5. Under Contacts, click Sync contacts from, and then click Outlook.

Or you can try to add your contacts in your iPhone :

**Settings** -> **Mails Contacts, Calendar** -> **Add an account**

And then just syncrhonize your contacts.

Comment: Thats what I thought...but want to post it here in case I missed any setting...I might have to add active sync to use the default contact app for my work contacts...

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone X with Outlook app installed, go to Settings >Accounts & Passwords >Accounts >Outlook >click the contacts button to on. This synced my Outlook contacts to iPhone contacts which now show when I receive a call from a contact.